# crystal volume of an irregular shaped natural box

Tags: geometry

I am trying to determine the volume of a crystal structure that looks cube shaped with 6 faces, but with variable lengths as shown [irregular cube](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJCzU.jpg)has only two

Comment: Are you certain those faces are actually *planar* quadrilaterals?

Comment: @Felix: did part of your question or statement get lost? Regards

Answer (score 1):

You can partition the shape into tetrahedra and compute each tetrahedron with vertices $\vec a,\vec b,\vec c,\vec d$ volume as $\frac16\Bigl(\bigl((\vec b-\vec a)\times (\vec c-\vec a)\bigr)\cdot (\vec d-\vec a)\Bigr)$ (beware of signs/orientation).

*Remark:* This assumes you have some 3D coordinates for the vertices, not just side lengths. Note that knowing the side lengths alone may not be sufficient.

Comment: Note that, from the data he has given us so far, he has edge lengths but not vertex coordinates.

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke Then I much doubt that the shape and its volume are uniquely determined.

Comment: Hi Joseph I don't have the 3D coordinates, however I do have the angles for each of the vertices. would this be sufficient for the partitioning.